# Tradução de Rótulo "em suspenso"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Acredito que **em suspenso** não seja uma boa tradução para a marcação de **on hold**. Como pode ser visto nesta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12309/api-last-fm-qual-metodo-mais-eficiente-para-retornar-a-foto-do-artista

**Em espera** poderia ser uma alternativa muito mais conveniente.

Comment: Por que voce acha que `em espera` é mais conveniente?

Comment: Porque é uma alternativa gramaticalmente correta e fiel ao significado.

Comment: E simplesmente "suspensa"?

Comment: +1 @bfavaretto soa melhor também!

Comment: Só eu que acho que é tudo a mesma coisa? Suspensa, em suspenso, em espera...

Comment: Posso mudar, mas a gente precisa chegar num consenso. "Suspensa" me parece boa, e os votos indicam isso também, mas seria melhor ter como uma resposta, e um pouco mais de tempo de discussão. Pode criar a resposta, @bfavaretto?

Comment: Ok @Gabe, feito.

Comment: @Math A (in)correção das locuções adjetivas e adverbiais formadas por ‘em’ + adjetivo não é consenso entre gramáticos. Essas locuções são galicismos também encontrados em espanhol e catalão; algumas delas têm uso frequente no registro coloquial brasileiro: em aberto, em absoluto e em anexo.

Comment: @Bavarious gostei da explicação, por mais que eu não tenha entendido 100%, mas é um bom embasamento para pedir a mudança do texto, talvez você devesse escrever como resposta

Comment: @Math Ha, na verdade foi uma defesa de que ‘em suspenso’ pode ser considerado correto. Não tenho preferência forte quanto a ‘em suspenso’ e ‘suspenso’.

Comment: @bavarious hahaha, entendi melhor seu texto agora, valeu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro usar somente a palavra ***suspensa***. É como eu tenho me referido em comentários às perguntas marcadas como "em suspenso".