# "Suspender" parece pior que "fechar"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução, localização, fechamento

Sei que fui [eu mesmo que sugeri](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1214/74) que as perguntas recém-fechadas fossem rotuladas como "suspensas" pelo [período inicial de 5 dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) até que sejam consideradas "fechadas". Porém, conversando com outras pessoas e pensando melhor sobre o assunto, percebi que isso não é muito simpático, principalmente para novos usuários. Passa a impressão de que eles fizeram algo *muito* errado para merecer algum tipo de "suspensão".

Pensei em algumas alternativas, mas nada que realmente ficasse melhor que o que tínhamos antes ("em suspenso"). Lembrando que em inglês é *on hold*, vocês têm sugestões melhores? Levem em conta também que não basta a tradução da palavra solta como adjetivo (como em "pergunta *suspensa*"), já que o termo também aparece em expressões como:

> **suspender** como $closeReason$ $onDate$
>   **suspensa** como $closeReason$ por $userCommas$ $onDate$

Comment: que tal "Em analise"?

Comment: Acho legal, mas já tem outra coisa no site que chama "análise", e podem confundir...

Comment: o mais próximo disso é "Em avaliação" ou se não ficamos com "Pendente" @JorgeB.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth e que tal "com pendências" ao invés de "pendente"? Porque para mim o autor da questão não vai entender de primeira que a responsabilidade é dele de editar, só depois que ler o texto, agora "com pendências" para mim parece que incentivaria ele a buscar os motivos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sugiro que coloque sua sugestão como uma resposta para que possa ser votada.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Obrigado

Comment: Pendente ficou muito bem já agora.

Comment: Me lembrou do Estado de [Animação Suspensa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o_suspensa), que ofereceria as opções Congelada e Zumbi :P

Comment: Relacionado: [Should we change “on hold” to “needs revision” or something similar?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298683/1964435)

Answer (score 10):

Eu pensei em **com pendências** ao invés de **pendente**.

Porque para mim o autor da questão não vai entender de primeira (com a palavra **pendente**) que a responsabilidade é dele de editar, só depois que ler o texto, agora **com pendências** para mim parece que incentivaria ele a buscar os motivos da questão dele estar assim.

Comment: Acho que o motivo não é válido. "com pendências" vai deixar o autor com a mesma ideia do que com "pendente". Com pendências porquê? Pendente porquê?

Comment: Acho que poderia restaurar sua outra resposta, eu gostei dela. Apesar de nem sempre a pergunta ter salvação, acho que para a maioria dos casos aquele texto se aplica. (Claro que eu mesmo poderia restaurar sua resposta, mas não fiz isso pois preferi ver se você concorda. Se não concordar eu vou postar aquilo como resposta em meu nome :) )

Comment: @Math Obrigado, restaurei :)

Answer (score 7):

Pensei em "em espera" que á a tradução de *on hold* ou "pendente".

Que dizem?

Comment: Eu gosto de "pendente", deixa bem claro que algo precisa ser feito. Só não sei como ficariam as traduções em todos os contextos onde o termo deve aparecer (ver minha edição na pergunta).

Comment: Onde usas o suspender como? @bfavaretto

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas o Gabe mencionou essas strings outro dia. Talvez na interface de análise, e/ou no diálogo de fechamento.

Comment: Por/Colocar pendente nesse caso. pendente como em vez de suspensa como

Comment: "Marcar como pendente"?

Comment: Assim fica porreiro.

Answer (score 7):

## A melhorar

Com isso, as perguntas ficarão assim:

> Por que laranjas são melhores que maçãs? [a melhorar]

E os motivos:

> Marcar como **a melhorar** porque $closeReason$ $onDate$
> Marcada como **a melhorar** por $userCommas$ porque **$closeReason$**. $onDate$

Ficando mais ou menos assim:

> Marcada como **a melhorar** por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda porque **não é claro o que você está perguntando**. 3 dias atrás
>
> Marcada como **a melhorar** por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda porque **a pergunta está fora do escopo**. 3 dias atrás
>
> Marcada como **a melhorar** por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda porque **a pergunta é ampla demais**. 3 dias atrás
>
> Marcada como **a melhorar** por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda porque **a pergunta é principalmente baseada em opiniões**. 3 dias atrás

O objetivo é convidar o autor da pergunta a melhorá-la, e portanto a melhor alternativa seria colocá-la como **a melhorar**.

Ou então assim:

> Marcada como **a melhorar** porque $closeReason$. Por $userCommas$. $onDate$

Ficando mais ou menos assim:

> Marcada como **a melhorar** porque não é claro o que você está perguntando. Por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda. 3 dias atrás
>
> Marcada como **a melhorar** porque a pergunta está fora do escopo. Por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda. 3 dias atrás
>
> Marcada como **a melhorar** porque a pergunta é ampla demais. Por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda. 3 dias atrás
>
> Marcada como **a melhorar** porque a pergunta é principalmente baseada em opiniões. Por Chaves, Chiquinha, Seu Madruga, Quico, Dona Florinda. 3 dias atrás

E quanto a este texto:

> Segundo os usuários, este foi o motivo para a suspensão:

Ficaria assim:

> Segundo os usuários, este foi o motivo pelo qual a pergunta foi marcada como a melhorar:

E os motivos de fechamento mudariam um pouco:

> "fora do escopo" -> "a pergunta está fora do escopo"
> "amplo demais" -> "a pergunta é ampla demais"
> "principalmente baseada em opiniões" -> "a pergunta é principalmente baseada em opiniões"

Comment: Não acho que "a melhorar" seja um bom termo... A mim não me soa muito bem, mas para além disso não faz sentido na frase: "Marcada como a melhorar porque a pergunta está fora do escopo". Ou faz?

Comment: @JorgeB. Porque ela poderia ser melhorada para ser colocada dentro do escopo.

Comment: Nem sempre @Victor. Imagine que eu pergunto: "Eu devo usar champô para cabelo oleoso ou anti-caspa?"

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, mas estes casos são super raros e extremamente absurdos. Acho que o benefício de colocar o "a melhorar", que cobre os 99% dos casos que interessam, é muito maior do que a necessidade de fazer o texto servir também para estes casos raros e extremos.

Comment: Eu exagerei um bocado, mas não são assim tão raros como este: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43983/como-remover-um-device-completamente-windows-8

Comment: @JorgeB. Ok, fica difícil servir para isso. Mas ainda acho mais compreensível/entendível para um usuário iniciante do que um "pendente". Vou tentar inventar uma outra coisa e colocar mais uma resposta.

Answer (score 7):

Para complementar o assunto:

Uma das coisas que me ocorreu é que a vantagem da "suspensão" e do "fechamento" sobre a negativação das perguntas ruins, é que negativação depende de a pessoa tirar o negativo. fechamento e suspensão são reversíveis por outros membros da comunidade.

Se o problema é o impacto que isto causa nos visitantes, é questão de melhorar a forma de dizer isto, para não parecer uma ofensa.

Isto envolveria mexer um pouco no sistema, mas se formos lembrar do discurso de que o site é nosso <sup>(evil grin)</sup>, que tal melhorarmos a UI da pergunta suspensa, pondo no box do fechamento (entre outras partes) algo mais ou menos nesta linha:

> Olá, FULANO. Esta pergunta precisa de sua atenção.
>
> Da forma como ela está formulada atualmente, é difícil de a comunidade ajudar, pois [texto conforme razão de fechamento].
>
> Que tal dar uma incrementada na pergunta? Você pode [instruções conforme razão da suspensão], e assim sua chance de ter sua dúvida resolvida aumenta bastante.
>
> Veja aqui algumas coisas que podem te ajudar:
>   [links pra documentação adequada para o caso]

Na mesma linha, apesar de um pouco mais comprido, o título da "suspensa" seria algo que desse o sentido de que a intervenção **do autor** é a chave para a continuidade:

> O que é melhor, pizza ou chocolate? [aguardando o autor]

Obviamente que isso é só um esboço, a idéia geral seria a UI refletir um senso de continuidade e de a comunidade estar ansiosamente esperando pra ajudar (meu exagero proposital aqui foi só para transmitir a idéia). As palavras podem e devem ser melhoradas, o importante é passar a mensagem pretendida de maneira clara.

Assim podemos usar a ferramenta certa pro uso certo, sendo amistosos e receptivos, mas sem precisar duvidar da capacidade dos usuários tratando-os como crianças.

Adendo "do mal" (mas necessário): se com esse convite amistoso a melhorar o autor não faz sua parte, e a coisa não tem o mínimo necessário para funcionar, infelizmente não tem muito o que fazer senão eliminar/remover (fechada fazendo ruído também é ruim). No soup for you.

Comment: Sou totalmente a favor da mensagem de fechamento mais amigável. Sobre o [aguardando o autor], tenho dúvidas, pois nem sempre é o caso. Talvez apenas para "não é claro..." e "ampla demais".

Comment: é, tem que ser "onde aplicável". É uma idéia geral, teria que ser aprimorada.

Comment: @bfavaretto Nos casos de "fora do escopo" ou "principalmente baseada em opiniões", às vezes é só o caso de o autor da pergunta não ter se expressado direito e ter sido mal interpretado. Pelo outro lado, às vezes o "não é claro" e o "amplo demais" também podem ocorrer de serem perguntas sem chance de salvação. Ou seja, em todos os casos o [aguardando o autor] pode ou não ser o correto.

Answer (score 2):

Segunda sugestão:

*Necessita de melhorias* ou *Precisa melhorar*

Baseado na ideia de que o texto pode ser "montado" como o [@gabe explicou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4057/perguntas-on-hold-com-novo-texto#comment10989_4057) explicou:

> @Math vai depender de como essa string é montada, e a disposição das partes dela no Transifex, mas algo como "Pendente de melhorias por ser ampla demais de acordo com usuario1, 2, 3, 4 e 5" pode dar certo. Além disso, usuario1, 2, 3, 4 e 5 podiam começar a editar as coisas ao invés de votar pra fechar em tudo :D

Comment: Mas nem sempre precisa de melhorias...

Comment: @JorgeB. Faz todo sentido, falta de atenção minha. Vou rever.

Comment: Eu voto por "Necessita de melhorias"

Comment: @JorgeB. não entendi seu ponto. Você quer dizer que por muitas vezes a pergunta não tem salvação e não há melhoria que ajude? Se for isso, diria que é um detalhe irrelevante.

Answer (score 1):

Gostei da sugestão de **pendente** mas ainda não estou muito satisfeito com a primeira frase:

> ***Declarar pendência** como $closeReason$ $onDate$*
>
> **Pendente** como $closeReason$ por $userCommas$ $onDate$

Está como wiki da comunidade para ver se mais alguém consegue ter alguma ideia para ajudar a melhorar e porque a ideia de pendente não foi minha.

Comment: "Marcar/marcada como pendente" pode ser uma boa pro primeiro contexto.

Answer (score -1):

Não esqueçam dos botões

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que neles o termo continua sendo "fechar". Porque o estado "pendente" (ou seja lá o que usarmos) é temporário, após 5 dias o rótulo muda para "fechada" caso a pergunta não seja reaberta.