# Poderiamos por favor ser um pouquinho mais agradáveis?

Tags: debate, comportamento, novos-usuários

Há um declínio distinto no nível de civilidade que vem tido no SO. Parte disso é devido a novos usuários chegando e postando spam e outras bobagens, mas os botões off-topic e downvote estão fazendo um bom trabalho em manter isso sob controle.

Infelizmente, muito disso vem de usuários mais experientes, e o sistema de moderação embutido no site não (e provavelmente não pode) lidar com isso muito bem. As pessoas estão correndo para esmagar os novos usuários com "isso pertence ao meta!", "Isso é off-tópic", "isso é uma duplicata!" e "leia o FAQ!". (O que é correto, mas deve ser feito de maneira mais instrutiva) Tudo isso, é claro, vem acompanhado por uma enxurrada de votos negativos. Isso não é muito acolhedor para novos usuários que não sabem sobre meta, o FAQ, ou o que conta como off-topic.

Agora, não estou propondo que apenas permitamos perguntas fora do tópico, meta ou duplicadas. No entanto, acho que podemos ser mais gentis na forma como expressamos esse tipo de coisa. Explique o que é meta e o FAQ e forneça links úteis. Apenas usando por favor e obrigado quando pedir às pessoas para ler o FAQ ou postar algo no meta, isso já seria uma grande melhoria. Eu também acho que nós poderíamos controlar o downvoting um pouco. Não que não devamos votar nas coisas, mas a menos que a postagem de um novo usuário seja claramente spam, votá-lo para -1 ou -2 deve ser suficiente para enviar uma mensagem sem se empilhar. Eu gosto do SO e quero que ele se torne um recurso para todos, não apenas um site elitista para usuários de alta reputação nos sites.

O Tour diz o seguinte:

> Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver uma
> biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta sobre
> programação.

Não fazemos o SO sozinhos, dependemos dos outros também, ainda mais dos novos usuários para que o SO continue sendo um espaço de aprendizagem.

Achei importante resgatar essa ideia contida no Meta SOen em [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

---

## Outros Detalhes

Bacco apontou muito bem o fato de que muitas vezes para usuários novos, a interface do SO pode não ser intuitiva o suficiente para que este compreenda o funcionamento do SO.

Comment: Pessoalmente acho aqui o SOpt bem calmo no que toca à conduta face aos novos usuários que postam tudo e mais alguma coisa sem sentido, desde copiar e colar enunciados e largar frases soltas, etc. Pelo que já presenciei no SOen, é normal ser bem mais duro com os novatos. É importante também lembrar que ser cordial e atencioso não está diretamente relacionado com o usar de "por favor" e "obrigado"

Comment: E o que você está fazendo para melhorar isto?

Comment: @Maniero é importante refletir como o coletivo pode se empenhar para melhorar neste ponto, uma andorinha não faz verão, não adianta tentar ser legal com os novos e então logo em seguida alguém trata o assunto de outra forma.

Comment: É que sempre tem destes *posts* onde a pessoa tem uma ótima intenção... que os outros façam mais. Pedir para os outros fazerem é fácil, é barato (grátis), é confortável, não dá trabalho, não toma tempo, não exige habilidade. E este é o motivo que não é como as pessoas querem. Para mudar tem que assumir a responsabilidade. Ninguém está deixando de fazer algo porque não sabem o que é para fazer, ou mesmo porque falta vontade. É que as pessoas passam o tempo todo aqui, fazem um esforço monumental, e ainda assim não é suficiente. Então se não tiver uma forma realista, este *post* não mudará algo.

Comment: @Maniero Não tiro seus motivos, mas sabe, esse "esforço monumental" tem suas razões, não é de graça que alguém passa tempo no SO, há motivos, dos mais variados. A comunidade é feita de gente, e essa gente vem e vai, nada é pra sempre, um dia eu não vou poder fazer parte mais do SO, nem mesmo você, e só por que eu e você não pode fazer parte do SO, a comunidade tem que se descontinuar? Se todo novo usuário não for bem tratado hoje não terá ninguém para manter esse legado amanhã.

Comment: @Maniero Com respeito a "pedir a outros é barato e fácil", este pedido não foi feito apenas por mim, a um certo tempo atrás apareceu no Meta SOen, eu achei relevante resgatar a ideia nele contida em https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Comment: Ninguem trata mal novato, salvo raros casos,  mas ninguem esta aqui lidando com criança pra falar "macio" nao. Eu sempre comento de forma fria e direta, pois imagino que so adultos participam do site. Agora, é dever de quem chega conhecer o local antes de querer fazer o que quer tambem, nào adianta vim aqui e jogar a culpa dos veteranos, muitos novatos nem se dao o trabalho de lerem ou acessarem os links informativos que postamos alguns até sao rudes em relacao a isso. Só acho que sempre aparece um pra culpar os veteranos, os novatos nunca tem culpa de nada.

Comment: @Articuno É preciso lembrar que aqui no SO crianças com 13 anos de idade já possuem o direiro garantido pelos termos de serviços a fazer uso do SO, veja https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age . Não estou culpando ninguém, na realidade estou propondo uma discussão saudável acerca do tema.

Comment: Creio que, assim como foi mudado para indicar quando  é um novo usuário, assim deveria ser forçado esse novo usuário a fazer o [tour] antes de publicar uma pergunta.

Comment: @NoobSaibot forçar o usuário a fazer o tour antes dele publicar uma pergunta seria uma péssima ideia e as chances de aumentar a evasão entre novos usuários seria altíssima. Muitas barreiras para concluir uma ação acaba gerando desistência.

Comment: @RORSCHACH o problema do seu post é o que pode ser considerado como *amigável* na visão de cada usuário aqui no SOpt. Claro que qualquer tipo de insulto ou ofensa resultara em punição. E mediar o mais agradável é dificil, não vou negar que os sites da SE são um mar de rosas para os usuários novos porque não são. No entanto, é preciso ilustrar casos específicos e apontar o problema para que possamos debater e encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Eu acho que o @Bacco tocou no ponto mais importante, a UI é um dos mais causadores deste pequeno efeito, pois não é intuitiva nem simples.

Comment: Não que isso justifique, mas vejo um reflexo da qualidade das perguntas. De uns tempos pra cá tem uma enxurrada de perguntas de baixa qualidade, e vejo que as pessoas acabam se cansando de comentar, sugerir a leitura do tour e de como fazer uma pergunta, como criar em exemplo verificável, etc, e acabam às vezes sendo mais ríspidos. Não que isso justifique, mas só noto que é um reflexo da quantidade  de perguntas de baixa qualidade

Comment: @RicardoPontual isso mesmo, e o sistema não ajuda, que é o que o Bacco está falando. Junta as duas coisas e cria-se um problema grande. O sistema deveria orientar melhor. Há bastante tempo contrataram uma pessoas "especialista" em UX, até agora praticamente não vimos mudanças, e onde teve é questionável se foi útil. Tem caso que piorou. Já pensou o quanto ajuda o sistema dizer que a pessoa é novata? O que você pode fazer se a pessoa é novata? Fazer de conta que as regras não existem pra ela? Fazer o que o sistema deveria fazer? Fica complicado...

Comment: Removi meus comentários anteriores, para evitar excesso de informação nos comments. e resumi na resposta a seguir.

Comment: @Maniero *"O sistema deveria orientar melhor"* também acho. Aquele assistente que o SO implementou ajuda, mas acho q ainda pode ser melhor. Fora que perguntas que já tem textos como *"E ai manos", "Preciso urgente", "Exercício: [só enunciado]", "Me dêem um código pronto"*, etc, já não atrai nenhuma empatia, dai os *downvotes* e comentários não sou amigáveis mesmo

Comment: @sam acredito que você e muitas outras pessoas fazem o possível, mas se tiver alguns comentários incentivadores, e um do tipo *"não estamos aqui pra fazer sua lição de casa"*, parece que esse último causa maior impacto infelizmente

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Penso que o post só faria sentido aqui se o problema estivesse ocorrendo aqui na mesma proporção que lá. O SOzão é muito "selvagem", aqui acho até que o pessoal é tolerante demais (também tem problemas, mas são pontuais).

Por outro lado, se seu post for sobre "ser educado", isso é princípio básico de civilidade. Não vai ser um post do meta que vai mudar isso (e quem lê o post normalmente é quem já sabe disso). Muitos não acompanharam, mas tivemos exaustivas discussões sobre isto aqui mesmo no meta, em posts e comentários, no chat, e é um assunto constante.

Note que eu acho louvável sua intenção e esforço, só que o efeito final do post acho que não é bem o que você espera, infelizmente. Ele só põe mais "pressão" em cima dos usuários ativos, que são os que já tem essa mesma preocupação que você.

### A fonte do problema

O momento que eu acho que estamos (mas isso depende da empresa, não dos usuários) é de melhorar a UI do site como um todo, pq ela não é muito amistosa.

Exemplo: tem um banner imenso na home, pra quem não está logado, que não ajuda em nada a orientar novos usuários. Tem uma breve explicação, mas não abre caminhos para quem quer entender melhor o site, não aponta pra lugar nenhum muito evidente, não convida a entender a ferramenta.

As mensagens de fechamento são frias, e não provocam leitura. Simples mecanismos, como um aviso de que downvote é uma coisa normal, explicações no fechamento de como proceder (bem didáticas) para resolver problemas do post, melhorariam a percepção do site como um todo. O primeiro passo no feedback negativo é a pessoa entender que aquilo é normal, que não é pessoal, nem castigo.

Sobrecarregar mais ainda os usuários para compensar falhas do sistema não é solução justa, no meu ver.

Um esforço conjunto para tentar levar estas questões de UI/UX mais "pra cima", talvez.

### Discussões relacionadas:

> [Estado da Pilha #1: Carinho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho)

> ["Suspender" parece pior que "fechar"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2316/70)

> [StackOverflow - Uma Sociedade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4499/70)

> [Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7165/70)

> [Campanha: Fechamento justo e explicado. Reabertura justa e explicada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2693/70)

Comment: Eu tenho um "projeto" para fazer um trabalho de discussão centralizada de UX, mas falta tempo. E claro incentivo, porque a gente sabe que algo próximo de zero será implementado.

Comment: @Maniero Não sei se eu que enxergo coisas que os outros não vêem, ou talvez eu esteja "muito louco" (sinceramente o meu dia a dia costuma provar que é o primeiro caso), mas muito da energia que a rede gasta em melhoria é posta no lugar errado. Pequenos detalhes fundamentais parecem ser adiados ou ignorados, e grandes saltos são dados em coisas talvez não tão importantes (e talvez postas em prática sem o devido projeto). O pessoal parece bom em levantar estatísticas, mas não em entender as causas elementares (ou, talvez seja minha falta de acesso aos dados ou entender os objetivos reais).

Comment: Totalmente, diagnóstico perfeito.