# Perguntas "on hold" com novo texto?

Tags: debate

Relacionados:

- [Tradução de Rótulo "em suspenso"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-r%C3%B3tulo-em-suspenso)
- ["Suspender" parece pior que "fechar"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2316/suspender-parece-pior-que-fechar)

Aparentemente as sugestões do [@Jorge B.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2341/3635) e [@Kyllopardiun](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2317/3635) "foram" as escolhidas.

Isto foi uma decisão interna?

De qualquer forma, acredito que realmente tenha ficado melhor que *[Suspensa]*.

Comment: Boa pergunta. Aparentemente a comunidade prefere a tradução "com pendências". Se assim for podemos mudar.

Comment: @Math foi o que imaginei também, apesar que foi apenas por um voto contra o do JorgeB., acredito que seria um "empate".

Comment: "com pendências" parece boa. Acho que é hora de um mutirão no Transifex

Comment: Mas @Gabe, como que ficaria por exemplo o texto na caixa amarela ([exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71823/3117))? "**com pendências** como amplo demais por usuário1, 2, 3, 4 e 5"

Comment: @Math vai depender de *como* essa string é montada, e a disposição das partes dela no Transifex, mas algo como "Pendente de melhorias por ser ampla demais de acordo com usuario1, 2, 3, 4 e 5" pode dar certo. Além disso, usuario1, 2, 3, 4 e 5 podiam começar a editar as coisas ao invés de votar pra fechar em tudo :D

Comment: Acho que "com pendências" ficaria no mínimo estranho... Acho que pendente está ótimo.

Comment: @Gabe +1 por "Além disso, usuario1, 2, 3, 4 e 5 podiam começar a editar as coisas ao invés de votar pra fechar em tudo :D"

Comment: Venho juntar a minha opinião à do @JorgeB. : "com pendências" fica estranho, pelo menos para quem é português.

Comment: @ramaral eu entendo que "com pendências" significa que "tem pendencias", a não ser que em portugual usem o "com" pra algo a mais que eu desconheço.

Comment: Eu também entendo assim e é português correcto, mas "soa mal" aos ouvidos portugueses, pelo menos aos meus. Não tem a ver se é "com" ou "tem" mas sim com a expressão em si. Como queremos *qualificar o estado* da pergunta o mais correcto é usar um adjectivo: [Pendente](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pendente) e não um substantivo: [Pendência](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pend%C3%AAncia).

Comment: @ramaral talvez por desconhecer o português de Portugal eu esteja confuso. Eu sugeri **com pendências**, pois para mim apenas [pendente] parece que está há outras pessoas analisando e não tem nada haver comigo (autor), [com pendencias] me parece que é algo que eu posso ver e até atuar na resolução. A minha ideia é realmente não usar "adjetivo", mas sim algo que faça a pessoa querer saber quais os problemas da pergunta. Se a pergunta tem pendencias eu posso querer saber quais são. Se a pergunta é "pendente" me parece que ela apenas está "travada".

Comment: Então  "pendente de melhorias", como sugerido pelo @Gabe, seria o melhor, apesar de ser um pouco comprido.

Comment: Mas nem sempre está "com pendências" ou "precisa de melhorias" as vezes precisa é estar fechada para sempre ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim tens razão. Talvez apenas [Pendências]?

Comment: Nossa piorou @GuilhermeNascimento, "pendente" para mim está ótimo.

Comment: Ora vejam aqui: http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pendente

Comment: Quando depende de alguém costuma se usar "dependente".

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento e @JorgeB. Eu acho que "pendente" é o melhor para ficar entre os colchetes [], e "Pendente de melhorias" seria o texto no aviso sob a pergunta. Entendo que "pendente" soa meio esquisito em pt-br, mas não é incompreensível e se é natural em pt-pt, não vejo problema

Comment: @Gabe Parece-me bem, mas temos o problema ""Pendente de melhorias como amplo de mais" ?!?!?!

Comment: @JorgeB. É.. não o trecho mais lógico do mundo, mas a gente provavelmente pode futucar mais. O trecho no Transifex é: "**fechada** como $closeReason$ por $userCommas$ $onDate$". Mantendo as 3 variáveis, nós podemos mexer como bem entendermos.

Comment: Ah não sabia disso @Gabe, vou pensar numa forma...

Comment: @Gabe "Pendente de melhorias como amplo de mais" não é tão mau assim mas "Pendente, para melhorias, como amplo de mais" talvez fosse melhor. Hesitei se havia de colocar as virgulas ou não.

Comment: @Gabe não é que soa estranho, apenas não dá a entender de primeira que o autor "talvez" possa colocar atuar na resolução.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu não pierei não, é apenas uma sugestão, talvez para você soe mal e para mim não, é apenas opinião, não vejo porque deste "pavor" rs.

Comment: Relacionado: [Should we change “on hold” to “needs revision” or something similar?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298683/1964435)